# jQuery mobile window height function returning incorrect values randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jQuery code to bind to the page create function:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','[data-role=page]', function() {
            $('.options_row').css('height', ($(window).height()-50)/2);
            console.log(($(window).height()-50)/2);
        });
```

This code is on my "home" page. I go to my login page and hit login, it redirects me to my home page. About 50% of the time this code is executed and the options_row elements will be resized and I will get a value of 292 outputted to my console (correctly). The other half of the time it will output 146.

Whenever I hit refresh on the homepage it will ALWAYS output the correct values (292). Even stranger: if I put an alert before applying the css, it will ALWAYS output the correct values.

Am I binding to the wrong function? Clearly there is some delay that needs to be hit for this code to grab the proper window.height.

Thoughts?

P.S. testing on chrome emulation it will load perfectly every time, from an S4/HTC ONE, its about 50% of the time.

Comment: Have you tried to bind it to a later event in the event like pageshow?

Comment: @Carlos487 pageshow defaults to the same behavior, asd does pageinit

Comment: Are you creating a Phonegap app or a mobile website? Also if the S4 is running android 4.4 KitKat you could debug the JS running on the device.